# Алгоритм Штрассена на C#

Tags: c#

Пишу курсовую работу по дисциплине Алгоритмы и структуры данных. Тема курсовой Алгоритм Штрассена. Ниже прикреплю код. Мой преподаватель не принимает такой код и просит не порождать новый матрицы, не заниматься пустопорожним копированием блоков из одного места памяти в другое, а также добавил "Примером является бинарный поиск в упорядоченном массиве. Там коллекция тоже разделяется, но не на физическом уровне, а посредством указания индексов левой и правой границ. В твоей программе надо разделять матрицу путём указания четырёх индексов: лев, верх, прав, низ.
Например, ты можешь в функции Add и Sub передавать не скопированные блоки, а четыре индекса исходной матрицы." Прошу помочь исправить мой код под его требования.
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static int[,] Strassen(int[,] A, int[,] B, int blockSize)
    {
        int n = A.GetLength(0);
        int[,] C = new int[n, n];

        if (n == 1)
        {
            C[0, 0] = A[0, 0] * B[0, 0];
        }
        else
        {
            int halfSize = n / 2;

            int[,] A11 = GetSubMatrix(A, 0, 0, halfSize);
            int[,] A12 = GetSubMatrix(A, 0, halfSize, halfSize);
            int[,] A21 = GetSubMatrix(A, halfSize, 0, halfSize);
            int[,] A22 = GetSubMatrix(A, halfSize, halfSize, halfSize);

            int[,] B11 = GetSubMatrix(B, 0, 0, halfSize);
            int[,] B12 = GetSubMatrix(B, 0, halfSize, halfSize);
            int[,] B21 = GetSubMatrix(B, halfSize, 0, halfSize);
            int[,] B22 = GetSubMatrix(B, halfSize, halfSize, halfSize);

            int[,] P1 = Strassen(AddMatrix(A11, A22), AddMatrix(B11, B22), blockSize);
            int[,] P2 = Strassen(AddMatrix(A21, A22), B11, blockSize);
            int[,] P3 = Strassen(A11, SubMatrix(B12, B22), blockSize);
            int[,] P4 = Strassen(A22, SubMatrix(B21, B11), blockSize);
            int[,] P5 = Strassen(AddMatrix(A11, A12), B22, blockSize);
            int[,] P6 = Strassen(SubMatrix(A21, A11), AddMatrix(B11, B12), blockSize);
            int[,] P7 = Strassen(SubMatrix(A12, A22), AddMatrix(B21, B22), blockSize);

            int[,] C11 = AddMatrix(SubMatrix(AddMatrix(P1, P4), P5), P7);
            int[,] C12 = AddMatrix(P3, P5);
            int[,] C21 = AddMatrix(P2, P4);
            int[,] C22 = AddMatrix(SubMatrix(AddMatrix(P1, P3), P2), P6);

            SetSubMatrix(C11, C, 0, 0);
            SetSubMatrix(C12, C, 0, halfSize);
            SetSubMatrix(C21, C, halfSize, 0);
            SetSubMatrix(C22, C, halfSize, halfSize);
        }

        return C;
    }

    static int[,] AddMatrix(int[,] A, int[,] B)
    {
        int n = A.GetLength(0);
        int[,] C = new int[n, n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                C[i, j] = A[i, j] + B[i, j];
            }
        }

        return C;
    }

    static int[,] SubMatrix(int[,] A, int[,] B)
    {
        int n = A.GetLength(0);
        int[,] C = new int[n, n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                C[i, j] = A[i, j] - B[i, j];
            }
        }

        return C;
    }

    static int[,] GetSubMatrix(int[,] matrix, int rowStart, int colStart, int size)
    {
        int[,] submatrix = new int[size, size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                submatrix[i, j] = matrix[rowStart + i, colStart + j];
            }
        }

        return submatrix;
    }

    static void SetSubMatrix(int[,] submatrix, int[,] matrix, int rowStart, int colStart)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < submatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < submatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix[rowStart + i, colStart + j] = submatrix[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение n для (2^n):");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int size = (int)Math.Pow(2, n);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[,] A = new int[size, size];
        int[,] B = new int[size, size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 10);
                B[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 10);
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Матрица A:");
        PrintMatrix(A); 

        Console.WriteLine("Матрица B");
        PrintMatrix(B);

        Console.WriteLine("Результат умножения матриц: ");
        PrintMatrix(Strassen(A, B, size));
    }
    static void PrintMatrix(int[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)